# Beck's problem: $A$-bounded and $A$-compact differential operators

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Trying to formalize Beck's problem from elastic stability with the help of operators, we have come across the following, which has been stated without proof in an old paper by Walker & Infante (1978): Given the operators (the space $H_2^{k}\left(0,1\right)$ is the Sobolev space of order $k$)
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
Ay&=\frac{d^4y}{dx^4},&D\left(A\right)&=\left\{y\in H^4_2\left(0,1\right)~\middle|~y\left(0\right)=y\left(1\right)=y^{\prime\prime}\left(0\right)=y^{\prime\prime}\left(1\right)=0\right\}\\
By&=-p^2\frac{d^2y}{dx^2},&D\left(B\right)&=\left\{y\in H^2_2\left(0,1\right)~\middle|~y\left(0\right)=y\left(1\right)=0\right\}\supset D\left(A\right)
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
then it holds that
\begin{equation*}
\left\|By\right\|\leq p^2\left<y,Ay\right>.
\end{equation*}
The estimate means that $B$ is $A$-bounded or realtively bounded (in the sense used in the literature). How did the authors of the paper mentioned above deduce it?

The estimate actually leads to my main question here: Can we derive the stronger result that $B$ is, in fact, $A$-compact or relatively compact?

*Restating the problem:*

I will rephrase the problem to make it more precise in a setting Walker & Infante (1978) also used in their paper: Consider the operator $A+B$ in the Hilbert space $L_2\left(0,1\right)$, where $A$ and $B$ are defined as above. Define now the product space $W=H\times L_2\left(0,1\right)$, where
\begin{equation*}
H=\left\{y\in H^2_2\left(0,1\right)\,\middle|\,y\left(0\right)=y\left(1\right)=0\right\}.
\end{equation*}
The inner product on $W$ is given by
\begin{equation*}
\left<w_1,w_2\right>_W=\left<y_1,y_2\right>_2+\left<y_1,y_2\right>_1+\left<z_1,z_2\right>_0,\quad w_i=\left(\begin{array}{c}
y_i\\
z_i
\end{array}\right)\in X,\quad i=1,2,
\end{equation*}
where
\begin{gather}
\left<y_1,y_2\right>_2=\int_0^1y_1^{\prime\prime}\left(x\right)\overline{y_1^{\prime\prime}\left(x\right)}\,dx,\quad \left<y_1,y_2\right>_1=p^2\int_0^1y_1^{\prime}\left(x\right)\overline{y_1^{\prime}\left(x\right)}\,dx,\\
\left<z_1,z_2\right>_0=\int_0^1y_1\left(x\right)\overline{y_1\left(x\right)}\,dx
\end{gather}
We can now work with two new operators $F$ and $G$ in $W$ defined as
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
Fw&=\left(\begin{array}{c}
z\\
-\frac{d^4y}{dx^4}
\end{array}\right),&D\left(F\right)&=D\left(A\right)\times H\\[0.5em]
Gw&=\left(\begin{array}{c}
0\\
p^2\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}
\end{array}\right),&D\left(G\right)&\supset D\left(F\right)\\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
So the estimate becomes:
\begin{equation*}
\left\|Gw\right\|_W\leq p^2\left<w,Fw\right>_W.
\end{equation*}
The ultimate goal, however, is to prove that $G$ is $F$-compact (or, equivalently, $\left(F+G\right)$-compact). In the literature you will often come across the statement "$G$ is $F$-compact", which is usually stated without proofs, however.

Comment: I see some problems in your question. (1) $D(B)\subset D(A)$ doesn't hold - it is actually the other way around. (2) In what norm / scalar product do you want the inequality? I guess you mean the $H^2_2$ setting?

Comment: Thanks, you are absolutley correct about the domains, I fixed it. I will provide the definitions of the inner products that I am working with in a minute.